# How to enable DLL building for windows in LLVM?

Tags: windows, gcc, dll, mingw, llvm

When I tried to build the LLVM source with a user defined module(which invoke add_llvm_loadable_module from CmakeLists.txt) I am getting following error -

> LlvmDisassembler ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this
>   platform.

I am building from the latest trunk and using MingW to build LLVM. Is there any way to build dll for LLVM modules in Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, build dynamical loadable module is not supported. It can be built as a static library and link to the main executable.